# Code Chunk Runs, But Will Not Knit: Error "Object Not Found"

Tags: r, knitr

I know this is a common problem for newbs, and I've looked around, but can't seem to find the solution.

This is the code that runs fine by itself, but will not knit:

```
lifters100 <- x1998short %>%
  sample_n(100)
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

[image: Error Message]

I also know that a knit pulls from a new environment, so I tried creating the object within itself with this:

```
x1998short <- x1998short
```

But that genius plan didn't work either.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you create `x1998short`? Is the code for that not in your document? Each time you knit, all the code is run in a new R session. The code needs to be self sufficient. Variables you create interactively will not be available.

Comment: @MrFlick `x1998short` was an object in a completely different project within my R studio. I had saved those objects as an Rdata file and moved them over to my current project (the one where `x1998short` is not working). So, obviously doing this affected the way that object was read when knitting.  Noted on your point about variables created interactively won't be available.  However, I'm lost on how to make them self-sufficient in a scenario like this.

Comment: Well, if you have them in an RData file, just make sure you have a `load("file.RData")` (or whatever the file name is) in the file you want to knit before you try to access the data.